# rndc flushname works from command line, but not from bash script

Tags: bash, dns, cron, bind

I am banging my head against the wall here trying to figure this out.  I have an automated DNS propagation system I am trying to build internally, and everything works except `rndc flushname`.  If I do this at a `shell` prompt

```
$ sudo rndc flushname /var/lib/bind/$domain.hosts
$ sudo rndc reload
```

This works

Also if I create the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
domain="some-domain.com"
# Do stuff 
rndc flushname /var/lib/bind/$domain.hosts
rndc reload
```

And run it

```
$ sudo bash myScript.sh
```

It works.

This command is not working if I assign the script to a cron job though IE

```
$ sudo crontab -e

 .... 
 ....

 */5 * * * * bash /etc/bind/dnsCron/dnsCron.sh
```

Why does `rndc` work from straight shell.  It also works manually called in a bash script.  But when called from crontab it doesn't reload?  All commands are run through `sudo` and the `crontab` is also running under root.  I am not sure what the issue is here?  Is there another method to call `rndc flushname` ?

Comment: You can redirect the output of your cron command to a file, and check it for errors. My guess would be that `rndc` is in /usr/sbin, and that is not in cron's (very minimal) PATH

Comment: OK I have changed it to full path --> `/usr/sbin/rndc flushname /var/lib/bind/$domain.hosts` -- Also keeping an eye on `/var/mail/root` as all my cron jobs output there.  I will report back after cron runs this next time ..

Comment: I feel stupid.  I should have known better!  Post this an an answer and I'll accept unless you can find this as a duplicated OP .. But I did search it out, I promise!